# How to perform zonal stats along a time series?

Tags: google-earth-engine, zonal-statistics

I'm working in the Google EarthEngine code editor and I try to extract some data from the Sentinel 2 dataset. I want to get the zonal statistic of a field along the time series, aggregating min, max and mean as a list.

for that I do the following:

```js
// Function to calculate and add an NDVI band
var ndvi = s2.map(function(image){
  return image.normalizedDifference(['B8', 'B4'])
});


var stat_ndvi = ndvi.map(function(image){
  
  var col = ee.FeatureCollection(geometry)
  var mean = image.reduceRegions({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.median(),
    collection: col,
    scale: 10,
  });
  
  var min_max = image.reduceRegions({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.minMax(),
    collection: col,
    scale: 10,
  });
  
  var filter = ee.Filter.equals({leftField: 'system:index', rightField: 'system:index'});
  var join = ee.Join.inner("mean", "minmax").apply(mean, min_max, filter)
  return join.map(function (feature){
    return ee.Feature(feature.get('mean')).copyProperties(feature.get('minmax'));
  }).flatten();
});

print(stat_ndvi)
```

But it doesn't work as the stat_ndvi featurecollection always have 0 columns.

I already checked:

- the system:index of each features are the same
- the properties are not empty in the generated featurecollection
- there are images on my little field (2)

What did I miss ?

here is the full executable script with the geometry and the S2 image selection: https://code.earthengine.google.com/305af3196569ddcc199dc06ef541242a

### EDIT

The resulting featurecollection has indead correctly shaped feature. each one have 3 properties (min, max and mean) the problem lies in the FeatureCollection which does not have the properties saved as column, preventing me from manipulating the resulting dataset.